# Use of Biometric Residence Permit for multiple visit to UK

Tags: united-kingdom, legal, residency

I have a Biometric Residence Permit (BRP) valid till Feb 2017, whereas vignette on passport is valid till April 2016. Can I visit UK again on BRP I have? If not do I have to follow any other process?

Comment: Flagging for migration to Expats.

Comment: @JoErNanO Are you sure? Phrasing the question in terms of "visiting" the UK suggests that it's a question about travel by somebody who was previously an expat.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I read this as a current UK resident wishing to travel in and out of the UK with their BRP only. I might be wrong, though.

Comment: Amol, could you clarify exactly what your situation is? Are you living in the UK at the moment?

Comment: I am indian resident currently living in India. I visited UK in March on dependent visa. I have BRP which is valid till Feb'17.But, vignette on passport shows validity till apr'16. I want to visit UK again. I am confused whether I can visit on BRP I have or I have to apply for visa again

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the status indicated by the biometric residence permit, and possibly on sok other facts.  From Timatic:

> Passport required.
>
> - Passports and other documents accepted for entry issued to residents of the United Kingdom must be valid on arrival.
>
> Visa required, except for Passengers with a Biometric Resident Permit issued by the United Kingdom if:
>
> - the last leave (permission) to enter or remain in the United Kingdom has not expired and was given for a period of more than six months; or
> - the last leave has not expired and was given by the stamp which reads: "Given leave to enter to complete previous leave Section 3(3)(b) ; or
> - alien resident is a permanent resident of the United Kingdom returning within two years (SEE NOTE 52453) of last departure; or
> - alien resident has the right of abode in the United Kingdom confirmed by a Certificate of Entitlement to the Right of Abode" vignette in the passport.
>
> NOTE 52453: The two year restriction does not apply to 
>   accompanying spouses and children of military personnel returning to the United Kingdom.
>
> Visa required, except for Passengers with an EEA Family Residence Card issued by the United Kingdom.
>
> Visa required, except for Passengers with an EEA Family Permit issued by the United Kingdom if the holder is traveling with, or to join the EEA or Swiss national.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use your Biometric Residence Permit to visit UK again. The permit prove that you are allowed to return to UK again. But it can't be use instead of your passport or any other travel documents.

Comment: Do you have any references for this?